# The expectation days that event 0 happens in the next three days

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

There are two events (0,1), with probability transition matrix $p = (a,b;c,d)$, assume we start at event $0$,so day 0 (today) $a^{0}=(1,0)$. then day 1 we have $a^{1}=a^{0}*p=(a,b)$, for day 2 we have $a^{2}=a^{0}*p*p=(a^2 + b c, a b + b d)$, and day 3 we have $a^{3}=a^{0}*p*p*p=(a (a^2 + b c) + c (a b + b d), b (a^2 + b c) + d (a b + b d))$.

Then how could I calculate the expected number of days during the next three days that event 0 happens? I am confused about the meaning of the transition matrix. Do I need to add up all the first entry of each $a^{i}$ or just using 3 times the first entry of $a^3$? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean the expected number of days that event "0 happened in last 3 consecutive days" occured first time?

Comment: Try to create a graph $G=(V, E), V=\{X_1, X_0, X_{00}, X_{000}\}$, where state $X_i$ means how many consecutive 0's you already got ($X_1$ means you just got 1). Edges are probabilties given in your transition matrix. Then you need to calculate expected number of transitions to get from $X_0$ to $X_{000}$

Comment: You are mixing up too many ideas here. At any time instant $n$, $n \geq 0$, the **system** being modeled by the Markov chain can be in _one_ of two **States** labeled $0$ and $1$ respectively. The State of the system at time $n$ is denoted by $a_n$ where $a_n \in \{0,1\}$, and you are told that $a_0 = 1$. The matrix $p$ tells us that $$P(a_{n+1}=0\mid a_n=0)=a,\quad P(a_{n+1}=1\mid a_n=0)=b=1-a,\\P(a_{n+1}=1\mid a_n=1)=d,\quad P(a_{n+1}=1\mid a_n=0)=c=1-d.$$ What you are being asked is, "Find $P(a_1=0,a_2=0,a_3=0\mid $a_0 = 0)$"

Comment: If $a_n = (\alpha,1-\alpha)$ denotes$\left(P(\text{State is }0),P(\text{State is }1)\right)$ so that $a_0 = (1,0)$ means that the System is in State $0$ at time $0$, than  then you are correct in writing $a_n = a_{n-1}*p$. But what you need to calculate is the probability that a System that _begins_ at State 0 _remains_ in State 0 for the next three days.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I do not understand the relationship between the joint probability and expectation, maybe my description has some problem, I try to used another way (sorry about language), what I mean is that the expected number of days during the next three days that event 0 happened, but the joint probability means that the probability that event 0 happens in each of the next three days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the *horrendous* notation where, for example, in
$$a^{2}=\cdots=(a^2 + b c, a b + b d)$$ the $a^2$ on the left means something quite different from the $a^2$ on the right, what this question seems to be asking is the following:

> Given a two-state Markov process with state transition matrix $p$, let $X_n, n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ denote a Bernoulli random that has value $1$ if the process is in State $0$ on Day $n$. Given that $X_0 = 1$, that is, the process is in State $0$ on Day $0$, what is the average number of times that the process is in State $0$ during Days $1$-$3$?  That is,
>   what is the (conditional) expected value of $X_1+X_2+X_3$ conditioned on $X_0 = 1$?

The linearity of expectation tells us that 
$$E[X_1+X_2+X_3\mid X_0 = 1] = E[X_1\mid X_0 = 1]
+ E[X_2\mid X_0 = 1] + E[X_3\mid X_0 = 1]$$
The OP has already calculated $P(X_n = 1\mid X_0 = 1]$ for $n=1, 2, 3.$ I have not checked these calculations for accuracy, but will simply point out that the expectations $E[X_n\mid X_0 = 1]$ are trivial to calculate once we know the values of $P(X_n = 1\mid X_0 = 1]$ for $n=1, 2, 3.$

Comment: Thanks for reforming my question, that's exactly what I want to ask.